# Wrong output for addition for below method in JS

Tags: javascript, math

This code must give the output of the total cash , but rather gives wrong output?
Can anybody please tell me what is wrong in it.

```
var cashRegister = {
   total:0,
   add: function(itemCost)
   {
      this.total += itemCost;
   }
};

var i;

for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   var a = prompt("Cost");
   cashRegister.add(a);
}
//call the add method for our items


//Show the total bill
console.log('Your bill is '+cashRegister.total);
```

Comment: It would help to show what the actual vs. expected output is. And if you actually looked at the actual output, I think you would get a pretty good hint ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your adding strings.

instead of:

```
this.total += itemCost;
```

try:

```
this.total += +itemCost;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to parseInt your input values because they are strings and you'll only concat them that way. So, try:

```
this.total += parseInt(itemCost, 10);
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/3x9AH/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
add: function(itemCost)
{
   this.total += parseInt(itemCost);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to add strings.

You should convert to a number, but be careful with arbitrary user input.

For example, none of the other answers will take into account the following inputs:

1. "foo"
2. "+Infinity"
3. "-Infinity"

Change this line:

```
this.total += itemCost;
```

to:

```
this.total += itemCost >> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat()` function, it used to parses a string argument and returns a floating point number.

```
this.total += parseFloat(itemCost);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem you have is that you are adding strings instead of numbers.

You can do something like this to fix it:

    `this.total += Number(itemCost);`

http://jsfiddle.net/